# ¿Cómo mostrar las 10 palabras más repetidas de un archivo txt usando Python?

Tags: python

Quiero aprender cómo mostrar las diez palabras más recurrentes en un archivo y mostrar cuantas veces se repiten en Python.
El archivo txt puede contener puntos, comas y caracteres especiales.
Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Por favor leer [ask] y [mcve]. Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar el código de lo que hayas intentado, explicando con claridad el problema o dificultad encontrada y el comportamiento deseado. Tal como está redactada tu pregunta, parece que nos pides que lo hagamos por ti. Así nunca aprenderás. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Haciendo uso de algunas funciones de utilidad proporcionadas por Python, el código puede reducirse a unas pocas líneas.

- El método `str.translate()` permite realizar múltiples sustituciones a la vez en una cadena. Las sustituciones a realizar se proporcionan en un parámetro que básicamente establece un mapeo de qué caracteres se quieren cambiar a qué otros se quieren poner en su lugar.
- Ese mapeo se crea con `str.maketrans()` y podemos usarlo para que todos los signos de puntuación se mapeen a espacios.
- `collections.Counter` implementa un contador. Le pasas una lista de lo que sea (en este caso de palabras) y te retorna un objeto que se comporta como un diccionario en el que cada palabra es una clave, y el valor es el número de veces que aparece repetida.  Este objeto además tiene el método `.most_common(N)` que te devuelve los N valores (palabras en este caso) más frecuentes.

Haciendo uso de estas facilidades, la cosa queda así:

```
from collections import Counter

entrada = txt

signos = ".,:;-[]{}()'\"@/¿?¡!"
a_espacios = str.maketrans(signos, " "*len(signos))
palabras = str.translate(entrada, a_espacios).lower().split()
contador = Counter(palabras)
print(contador.most_common(10))
```

Si le meto como texto de entrada el Quijote, que se puede obtener así:

```
txt = requests.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jsdario/"
            "6d6c69398cb0c73111e49f1218960f79/raw/8d4fc4548d437e2a7203a5aeeace5477f598827d"
            "/el_quijote.txt").text
```

el resultado que sale es:

```
[
 ('que', 10738), ('de', 9043), ('y', 8684), 
 ('la', 5014), ('a', 4818), ('en', 4047), 
 ('el', 3857), ('no', 3122), ('se', 2382), ('los', 2150)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Cosas a tomar en cuenta

- Los caracteres:

  Es necesario eliminar los símbolos que podrían obstaculizar la comparación de las palabras, tales como las comas, puntos, paréntesis, etc. Ya que ***palabra!*** y ***palabra*** no son lo mismo.
- Las mayúsculas:

  Para que la comparación no falle en casos como ***Palabra*** y ***palabra***.

### Solución

```
# Texto usado: 
# Lorem Ipsum! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
# Integer sem enim, eleifend et iaculis eu.

# Abre y lee archivo txt
with open('archivo.txt', 'r') as f:
    texto = f.read()

# Lista de caracteres no deseados   
no_deseados = [',','.','¡','!','¿','?','(',')','"',"'"]
for char in no_deseados:
    texto = texto.replace(char,'')

# Crea lista de palabras convertidas en minuscula
palabras = texto.lower().split()

def cuenta_repetidas(p, palabras):
    """ Cuenta las palabras de la lista """
    return {p:palabras.count(p)}

# Obtiene una lista de diccionarios con key: palabra y value: n. de veces repetida
dict_list = [cuenta_repetidas(p, palabras) for p in palabras]

# Elimina los resultados repetidos 
resultados = [i for n, i in enumerate(dict_list) if i not in dict_list[n + 1:]] 

# Ordena los resultados
res_ordenados = sorted(resultados, key=lambda d: list(d.values()), reverse=True)

# Obtiene los primeros 10 resultados
primeros10 = res_ordenados[:10]

# Imprime los primeros 10 resultados
for d in primeros10:
    for k, v in d.items():
        print(k, v, sep=': ')
```

### Devuelve

```
lorem: 2      
ipsum: 2      
dolor: 1      
sit: 1        
amet: 1       
consectetur: 1
adipiscing: 1 
elit: 1       
integer: 1    
sem: 1
```